# Is it true that this entry can always be chosen in such a way that the matrix obtained has 0 determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

All the entries of an $n × n$ matrix are fixed with the exception of one entry. Is it true that this entry
can always be chosen in such a way that the matrix obtained has 0 determinant?

I thought in order to $det$ to be 0 there must two proportional rows(columns) or 0 row(column). So with only one entry it is not always possible. Is it proof?

Comment: No this is not true. Take the identity matrix, and change any off diagonal $0$ entry. You can change it to whatever you want, but the matrix still has determinant $1$ (since this matrix is still triangular and so the determinant will the be the product of diagonal entries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the Laplace expansion of the determinant along the row or column containing the given entry. If the cofactor of that entry is not $0$, there will be a unique value of the entry that makes the determinant $0$.  If the cofactor is $0$, the value of this entry does not affect the determinant.

Comment: So if the cofactor is not 0 then this entry can always be choosen in that way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways for the determinant to be zero besides the two ways you described.

The determinant is zero if and only if the $n$ columns are linearly dependent. (Note that having proportional columns and having a zero column are special cases of this.)